# C# LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists; `List<int> numList` has identifier number as its elements, and `List<string> filePaths` has path to file that needs to be analyzed as its elements. I want to filter `filePaths` based on the `numList`; that is, I only want to select the filePaths whose file names have the identifier number that is present in the `numList`.

For example, `filePaths` has

```
C:/test/1.test.xlsx
C:/test/2.test.xlsx
C:/test/3.test.xlsx
C:/test/4.test.xlsx
```

and, `numList` has

```
1
2
```

In this case, I want to construct LINQ statement to only get

```
C:/test/1.test.xlsx
C:/test/2.test.xlsx
```

I tried

```
for(int i = 0; i < numList.Count; i++)
{
    filePaths = filePaths.Where(f => Convert.ToInt32(GetNumberFromString(Path.GetFileName(f))) == numList[i]).ToList();
}
```

And this is GetNumberFromString Helper Method

```
// Find number in the string
private string GetNumberFromString(string value)
{
    int number;

    string resultString = Regex.Match(value, @"\d+").Value;

    if (Int32.TryParse(resultString, out number))
    {
        return resultString;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception(String.Format("No number present in the file {0}", value));
    }
}
```

I think this will work, but is there more elegant/efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: Is the path (C:/test/1.test.xlsx) would be always like that? (only the number will change) Or you want a generic function that works on any path?

Comment: Path can be any, but all the files will be in the same folder.

Comment: `var result = filePaths.Where(path => numList.Any(num => path.Contains(num))).ToList()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a one-liner:

```
var filteredFilePaths = filePaths.Where(x => numList.Contains(GetNumberFromString(x));
```

Comment: Just for clarification, GetFileNumber is equivalent to GetNumberFromString() method right? Like, it is not a built-in function

Comment: Correct yes. Changed my answer. I aldo tried Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension() but that returns 1.test, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this. The test method assumes that all the files in `directory` have appropriately formatted names. If that's not a reasonable assumption, it's easy enough to fix.

This is overkill, however, if you only ever care about the "file number" in one place.

```
public class TestClass
{
    public static void TestMethod(String directory)
    {
        var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory).Select(f => new FileInfo(f)).ToList();

        var numList = new[] { 1, 2 };

        var oneAndTwo = files.Where(fi => numList.Contains(fi.FileNumber)).ToList();
    }
}

public class FileInfo
{
    public FileInfo()
    {
    }
    public FileInfo(String path)
    {
        Path = path;
    }

    public int FileNumber { get; private set; }
    private string _path;
    public String Path
    {
        get { return _path; }
        set
        {
            _path = value;
            FileNumber = GetNumberFromFileName(_path);
        }
    }

    public static int GetNumberFromFileName(string path)
    {
        int number;

        var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);

        string resultString = Regex.Match(fileName, @"\d+").Value;

        if (Int32.TryParse(resultString, out number))
        {
            return number;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(String.Format("No number present in the file {0}", path ?? "(null)"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A stand-alone One-liner using a Join :

```
var result = filePaths.Select(x => new { Filename = Path.GetFileName(x), x })
    .Join(numList, x => Regex.Match(x.Filename, "^([0-9]+)").Value,
                   y => y.ToString(), 
                   (x, y) => x.x);
```